# Table header cells ( th ) in different background color in CSS

Tags: css, tableheader

I have following CSS style to show table data in proper format , but I want to display alternate background of table header ( th ) in different color...

How can I modify only below CSS to achieve the same
i.e every TH3,TH5 should have blue background ( except the first one TH1 - it will have default background of red )
while TH2,TH4,TH6 should have yellow background.

I have already tried nth child selector and somewhere I read about th+th both ways are not working.

```
 <style type="text/css">
    table {
           /*...all table attributes like fontsize etc*/
            font-size:11px;
            color:#333333;                
    }
    table th {
            /*...all th attributes like padding etc*/
            background-color:#d4e3e5;
            padding: 8px;
    }
    table td {
            /*...all td attributes like padding etc*/
            padding: 8px;
    }
    </style>
```

Thanks for all reespons but nth child selector is not working and I have alerdy tried that. Is there any basic way to modify the CSS and achieve the same?

Comment: use th:nth-child(odd) and  th:nth-child(even)

Comment: Thansk for info!! @PRAH i already told nth child option is not working in my CSS.

Comment: can you create the jsffidler for it, and can you also point which browser and version you are testing

Comment: @PRAH .. actually the above CSS is called by the jar file which is called by my unix script. So I am afriad that i will be able to provide jsffidler.

Comment: You could use `th+th...` syntax, it will be tedious, but working...

Answer (score 1):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/j5hsd8w3/)

nth-child is working.

```
 th:nth-child(odd) {
     background-color:red; // Replace it with your desired color
 }

 th:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: yellow;
 }
```

If you have problems furhter, post your HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

> TH3,TH5 should have blue background ( except the first one TH1 - it will have default background of red ) while TH2,TH4,TH6 should have yellow background.

If my understanding is correct, you are looking for something like this.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header1</th>
            <th>Header2</th>
            <th>Header3</th>
            <th>Header4</th>
            <th>Header5</th>
            <th>Header6</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
            <td>Data 5</td>
            <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table,tr,th,td{
/*...all table attributes like fontsize etc*/
   font-size:11px;
   color:#333333;
   border-collapse:collapse;
   border:1px solid;
}

table tr>th{
   background-color:red;
   padding:8px;
    }
table tr>th:nth-child(odd):not(:nth-child(1)){
    background-color:blue;
    padding:8px;
}
table tr>th:nth-child(even){
    background-color:yellow;
    padding:8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
th:nth-child(odd) { 
    background-color:blue; 
}

th:nth-child(even) {
     background-color:yellow; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        th:nth-child(odd){ background-color:blue; }
        th:nth-child(even){ background-color:yellow; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>heading</th>
            <th>heading1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>yyy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>xxx1</td>
            <td>yyy1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
table th:odd {
    background-color:#000; //Replace it with your desired color
}

table th:odd {
    background-color:#f00; //Replace it with your desired color
}
```

Or you can try selecting of nth element.

```
th:nth-child(n) {
    background-color:red; // Replace it with your desired color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to address a specific cell position of the table head (th), i use the following code:

`th:nth-child(4) { background-color: #7F7F7F; }`

4 = forth position from left side in table head (th)